# Go to GPS settings using javascript

Tags: javascript, gps

There is a way to open GPS settings using javascript?

I create an app that use GPS with phonegap. I have to check if gps is turn on or off. If GPS is turn off, i have to go in GPS setting.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

i just made a plugin for phonegap that display a dialog when GPS is disabled and redirect to location settings.

[cordova-dialog-gps](https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps)

Hope that help you.